# How to connect GTK+ signals (not gtkmm) to non-static class methods using libsigc++?

Tags: c++, gtk, libsigc++

The goal is to connect GTK+ signals to non-static class methods using libsigc++ without gtkmm. I want to use the Glade user interface designer to design a non-trivial UI with many views, comparable to a setup wizard. The UI should be portable (Embedded Linux and Windows). So, I want to reduce the dependencies and use the C GTK+ only without the C++ language binding component *gtkmm*, but the UI should be written in C++. The MVC pattern should be applied to separate the responsibilities and for decoupling. As a result, my C++ views and other classes have to connect their signal handlers to the GTK+ C signals using `g_signal_connect()`. Later they have to use `g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func()` to disconnect the handlers. The following example demonstrates the problem:

**File: GladeProgram.h**

```
#ifndef _GLADEPROGRAMM_H
#define _GLADEPROGRAMM_H

#include "gtk/gtk.h"

class GladeProgram
{
public:
  GladeProgram(int argc, char *argv[]);
  virtual ~GladeProgram();

  void Run();
  void Exit();
};

#endif // !_GLADEPROGRAMM_H
```

**File: GladeProgram.cpp**

```
#include "GladeProgram.h"
#include "sigc++/sigc++.h"

GladeProgram::GladeProgram(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
}

GladeProgram::~GladeProgram()
{
}

// C-style callback method with object pointer
void onExit(GladeProgram* pProg)
{
  pProg->Exit();
}

void GladeProgram::Run()
{
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GtkWidget  *window;

  builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("window_main.glade");

  window  = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));    

  // C-style signal handler with object pointer
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(onExit), this);

  // PROBLEM: Howto connect non-static class method GladeProgram::Exit() with libsigc++ ???
  // g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK( ??? ), NULL);

  g_object_unref(builder);

  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();
}

void GladeProgram::Exit()
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}
```

**File: Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GladeProgram.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "**********************************************************************" << endl;
  std::cout << "*                             GTK+ Test UI                           *" << endl;
  std::cout << "**********************************************************************" << endl;

  GladeProgram prog(argc, argv);

  prog.Run();

  // wait until the Enter key is pressed
  cout << endl << "Press [Enter] to exit." << endl;  
  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

The test program (console program) currently runs on Windows 10 and is compiled with Visual Studio 2017.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The most simple solution which comes in mind: Write a static member function with the signature required by the signal, and pass the instance pointer as client pointer. Then, the static wrapper may call the passed client pointer (with type cast from `void*` to object pointer) with your intended member function. As a side effect, your non-static member function even doesn't need to match the signal signature anymore. (If the resp. member function is `public`, a free function instead of the `static` member function would be sufficient as well, of course.)

Comment: @Scheff: Thanks for your answer. But something comparable I already did with `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(onExit), this)`. I wanted to know how to achieve this with the libsigc++, e.g. with `sigc::mem_fun()`?

Comment: Are you sure that sigc++ is compatible to GTK+? I doubt. Btw. I've used sigc++ with `memfun`, `ptrfun`, `bind`, and `hide` for years (but in gtkmm). The latter often drove me crazy as I could never remember the correct order. Now, with lambdas, there is a much more convenient alternative. Maybe, (non-capturing) lambdas could be a more convenient alternative in your case as well. Did you already try this?

Comment: @Scheff: From my knowledge gtkmm uses libsigc++ to provide signals. I thought, the lib is also used (internally) to wire the C-style callbacks and somebody knows how. The code above is straightforward/clear enough (maybe with the static methods you recommened instead of the C functions) to be used in a C++ project, I guess. The idea was to check whether there is an in-built way in libsigc++. I have not used lambdas in C++, in C# of course. Sounds interesting, can you extend my example with that?

Comment: I've nothing at hand to try this on my side. You may try this: `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK([](GladeProgram *pProg) { pProg->Exit(); }), this);`.